# Google Pay API - Insert a Pass to the Google Pay App without the JWT

Tags: android, rest, jwt, android-pay, google-pay

As the title suggest, I need help regarding the insertion of a Pass object into the Google Pay App (Android App) without the need for the user to go through the received JWT on the custom client App.

The scenario which I am following is the one based on the description on the Google site. In this approach, a class and an object are created and inserted on the custom Server side based on the request from the Android Client App. As a response, a JWT token created using the Google Pay API is returned on which the user needs to click and link itself with the Google Pay App (hence, to further click "Save" to actually save the pass).

Is it possible to directly insert the object and link it with the Google Pay account without receiving first the JWT and requiring the user to handle it? 
The idea is to process this in the background when the local ticket is created and to free the user from always having to save each individual Ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, the user has to explicitly save the pass. However you can group event tickets as per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/event-tickets/use-cases#group-event-tickets) and have multiple tickets saved in one button.